# How do I check for player death? (roblox studio)

Tags: lua, roblox

I have this script that I'm using to control when a player dies from hunger and or thirst. I am using a while statement to control the health reduction when a player has no food or water. I also have another while statement to reset the hunger and thirst when the player has less than or equal to zero `Health`. But it does nothing when I run the script.

```
local data = require(workspace.playerStats)
local player = script.Parent
local humanoid = player:WaitForChild("Humanoid");

data.hunger = 0
data.thirst = 0

while data.hunger or data.thirst <= 0 do
    wait(0.1)
    humanoid.Health-=1
end

while humanoid.Health <= 0 do
    data.hunger = 100
    data.thirst = 100
end
```

In case it is important, I have this script located in `StarterPlayer.StarterCharacterScripts`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first while statement yields, disallowing the code to reach the other while statement. Using spawn creates a new thread and allows the code to continue.

```
local data = require(workspace.playerStats)
local player = script.Parent
local humanoid = player:WaitForChild("Humanoid");

data.hunger = 0
data.thirst = 0

task.spawn(function()
    while data.hunger or data.thirst <= 0 do
        wait(0.1)
        humanoid.Health-=1
    end
end)

while humanoid.Health <= 0 do
    data.hunger = 100
    data.thirst = 100
end
```

for detecting death, I recommend using the Humanoid.Dead event.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was a mixture of what `I suck at everything` said something I did wrong. in the while statement I wrote

```
while data.hunger or data.thirst <= 0 do
-- code here
end
```

The thing I did wrong was the fact that I didnt add <= to both sides of `or`

so this is the correct code

```
while data.hunger <= 0 or data.thirst <= do
-- code here
end
```